# How to use buildscript dependencies in custom classes?

Tags: groovy, gradle, build-script

I am using a couple of helper classes with my build script, the folder structure looks like

```
buildSrc    
  -src   
     -main    
       -groovy
           GitUtils.groovy
build.gradle
```

In GitUtils I am trying to import a couple of classes (from grgit & http-builder in this example) used in a custom library. But it does not work, I get "Unable to resolve class XXX" exceptions. These classes are resolved fine if they are in build.gradle.

Relevant part of build.gradle:

```
buildscript {    
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.3.0'
    classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.3.0'
  compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'
}

...
GitUtils.doStuff();
```

Comment: do you have `apply plugin: 'groovy'` in your build.gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clean solution is to declare the dependencies you have in GUtils in your buildSrc/build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin:'groovy'

repositories {
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
  compile gradleApi()
  compile 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.3.0'
  compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'
}
```

Comment: thanks, adding a buid.gradle file into buildSrc solved it

Answer (score 0):

Since your `buildSrc` class is in groovy, please ensure the following are included in your build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.1'
}
```